# How to configure Firefox to warn or reject SHA-1 signed certificates?

Tags: firefox, certificate, hashing, security-warning

Is there a way to configure Firefox either through an add-on, plugin, or other setting that will either reject or warn whenever it encounters a certificate that has been signed using SHA-1?

Comment: [this](http://blog.yjl.im/2013/12/disabling-tlsssl-rc4-in-firefox-and.html#8011-disabling-in-firefox) discribes how to disable RC4 Ciphers

Answer (score 2):

If you want a warning you could use various Firefox plugins:

- [SSleuth](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/ssleuth/) It shows a value of how secure your connection is - SHA-1 leads to low score.
- [CipherFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/cipherfox/) Similar, but warning not very prominent.
- [CipherFox Secure](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/cipherfox-secure/) Fork of the above with more features.